# HTML won't run JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

The issue it that I can't get a simple JavaScript function to run with HTML. I get an error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: getYear is not defined".Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function getYear(){
    document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; <script> getYear()</script> | All rights reserved</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getYear` function creates only after the document is ready. Move the function declaration outside the `ready` callback

Comment: You've declared your function inside the "ready" handler. That makes it unavailable to anything outside that scope.

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Comment: [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's because you wrapped the function in your js file in a document.ready state
so you're unable to access the function inside your HTML footer tag because of that.

removing the document.ready will solve the issue.

your new code should be

```
  function getYear(){
    document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove ready function, because this function waits that all page onload, only use:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     
  function getYear(){
    document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
  }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; <script> getYear()</script> | All rights reserved</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <footer>
        <p> &copy; <script>
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
            </script>| All rights reserved </p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not need the

```
 $(document).ready(function () {...
```

Your new code should be like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

function getYear(){ return  new Date().getFullYear();  }

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; <script> getYear()</script> | All rights reserved</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```